# Why does resolving a promise with a proxy and then calling 'then' access the Proxy's getter?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-proxy

Here's a minimal example:

```js
const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get (target, name) {
    console.error('Getter ' + name + ' should not be called')
  }
});

const promise = Promise.resolve(proxy);

promise.then((proxy) => proxy);
```

In my mind, the call to `then` is accessing the property on the `Promise`, and so the getter on `Proxy` should never be accessed in the above example. Is this expected behaviour, or a bug? And, if it is expected, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

promise.then on its own is just fine, and is not invoking the proxy. For example, add in the following line of code, and you won't see an additional use of the proxy:

```
const temp = promise.then;
```

Instead, this comes down to the specification for promises. When you call `resolve(proxy)`, part of the promise resolution procedure includes checking the value of `proxy.then`. Then based on whether proxy.then is a function or not, it affects how the resolution process continues. Since proxy.then is being accessed, you're seeing the log statements.

See section 2.3 of the [Promise A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/), in particular subsection 2.3.3.1

Comment: That explains it perfectly. Great reply